# How to insert an image or video in html?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I have a django page that shows me a video loaded from a directory. I have a form with a drop-down list:

```
<form name="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" 
action="" name="formulario">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option selected>Select the type of file</option>
    <option>Video</option>
    <option>Picture</option>
    <option>Gif</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload"/>
<a href="{% url 'fileupload:delete' %}" onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the files?')" class="btn btn-success">Delete Files</a>
```

What I intend to do is that if the drop-down list selects video, I will insert a video and if I select a picture, I will insert an image. For example:

```
{% if valor == video %}
<video src='{{videofile.videofile.url}}' width="640" height="480" controls autoplay></video>
{% endif %}
{% if valor == picture %}
<img src='{{videofile.videofile.url}}' width="640" height="480" controls autoplay></video>
{% endif %}
```

In the project I have a static folder where the files are stored, either images or videos, so the user searches for the image or video, this is saved in the folder and is displayed on the page. How could I do this?

Regards.

Comment: Sounds good. Did you have a *question*?

Comment: Yes, How could I do this?

Comment: Well your above approach looks good. Which part of it are you struggling with?

Comment: Sounds like a Django question more than an HTML question.

Comment: Here:' ` {% if valor == video %}
<video src='{{videofile.videofile.url}}' width="640" height="480" controls autoplay></video>
{% endif %}. ` ' I don't know how to declare the select tag in the if, so that it recognizes me which tag was selected.